# React custom hook with event listener not works while updating the state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a custom hook that handles clicks outside of a component:

```
const useOutsideClick = (ref, callback) => {
  const handleClick = e => {

    if (ref.current && !ref.current.contains(e.target)) {
      callback();
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("click", handleClick);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("click", handleClick);
    };
  });
};
```

I have used this hook in a component like this:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const container = useRef();
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  useOutsideClick(container, () => {
    console.log("clicked outside");
  });
  return (
    <>
      <span>another element</span>

      <button onClick={() => setIsOpen(false)}>click</button>
      <div ref={container}></div>
    </>
  );
};
```

The problem is when I click on the span, everything works fine. But, when I click on the button an it updates the state, it doesn't enter useOutsideClick callback function. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that `useEffect` has no dependency array, so it is being called on every render. Also, it is better to keep the definition of `handleClick` inside the hook as it is only going to be used in the first render; otherwise if would be defined on every render.

```
const useOutsideClick = (ref, callback) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        const handleClick = e => {
            if (ref.current && !ref.current.contains(e.target)) {
                callback();
            }
        };

        document.addEventListener("click", handleClick);

        return () => {
            document.removeEventListener("click", handleClick);
        };
    }, []);
};
```

Comment: You right! I copied this code from medium and I didn't see this problem!

Answer (score 0):

I found that the best solution for useOutsideClick hook is this:

```
function useOutsideClick(ref, handler) {
  useEffect(
    () => {
      const listener = event => {
        if (!ref.current || ref.current.contains(event.target)) {
          return;
        }

        handler(event);
      };

      document.addEventListener("mousedown", listener);
      document.addEventListener("touchstart", listener);

      return () => {
        document.removeEventListener("mousedown", listener);
        document.removeEventListener("touchstart", listener);
      };
    },

    [ref, handler]
  );
}
```